# I am having issues with the subdivision surface modifier. When I don't add loop cuts it rounds when I do it makes a ridge.

Tags: modeling, objects, edges

I am making a basic model of a Porsche 944 as my first car model and I am having issues around the fenders. I have made the hood already and am now working on the part of the car just below the hood. I have duplicated all the edges around the perimeter of the hood and made into a new object (fenders). That in theory means that all of my edges along the hood line up but the problem I am having is I work best with the subdivision surface modifier so as a result it is rounding my edges and I am getting a gap between the fenders and hood. I know the trick of using loop cuts to give it a hard edge but that worked on only 3 of the 4 edges. On the fourth edge which is where the mirror modifier becomes present I can add the loop cut and it solves the issue of the gap but I then get a ridge down the middle of my car that I can not work out with shading. I have attached some pictures so you can see the problem.Hopefully some one has a solution to this madness and any advice helps.The first picture is of the gap I have between the fenders and hood,  it can be seen where the cursor is. The second is of the loop cut I add which fixes the gap. I can not post three pictures but the result of the loop cut sis the gap is gone but a ridge appears right on the center line. *Note* I have mirror modifier on and I am not getting ridges anywhere else.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you want that fourth edge loop, the picture with it missing looked fine to me? where is this gap?

Comment: Sorry I was not more specific. In the first picture just above the cursor you can see a crack along the two objects that slowly fades as it gets farther away from the center. In the second picture the fourth edge loop gets rid of the gap but it leaves a ridge along the center line. Unfortunately I can not include another picture to show.

Comment: Have you tried sub surfing both objects?

Comment: Now that you mention it, the hood of my car is not sub surfed. I will try that. Thank you very much for that suggestion.

Comment: Note to any others reading this, that did solve my problem